# cant get array to print in c

Tags: c

Why wont the array print I'm using c not c++. what am I doing wrong? I would also like to know what characters you can use in a char variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int map[4][4] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,11,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}; 
   int x, y;
   for (x = 0; x < 4; x++);
   {  
     for (y = 0; y < 4; y++);
     {    
       printf ("%i ", map[x][y]);
     }
     printf ("\n");
   }   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you compile and run your code?

Comment: What output do you get, and how is it different from what you want?

Comment: what errors you're getting?

Comment: Also, you can store any ASCII character in a `char` variable.

Comment: its prints just one 1. it wont print the whole array.

Comment: It's probably just a typo, but note that you've only got 15 elements in `map`. You need a comma between the 7th and 8th `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snippet from you code:

```
for (x = 0; x < 4; x++);
  {  
   for (y = 0; y < 4; y++);
```

Those semicolons at the end of lines. They mean, your for loops do nothing, they are taken as loop bodies.

Comment: @user2128021 To avoid this particular mistake: 1st, use an auto-indenter (Visual studio has that, as do other IDEs, and in Linux there's de-facto standard `indent` tool). 2nd, use indentation convention of putting the opening `{` on the same line as the `for`. Then if you see it alone in a line after a `for` line, you immediately know something is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of the ';' on both the for lines :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
 int map[4][4] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,11,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}; 
 int x, y;
  for (x = 0; x < 4; x++)
  {  
   for (y = 0; y < 4; y++)
   {    
    printf ("%i ", map[x][y]);
   }
    printf ("\n");
   }   
  system("PAUSE");  
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the semicolons on your for loops:

```
for (x = 0; x < 4; x++)
   {  
     for (y = 0; y < 4; y++)
     {    
       printf ("%i ", map[x][y]);
     }
     printf ("\n");
   }
```